# Razor: add total lines in a table

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have a simple IEnumerable that I am writing to a  in a cshtml page.
I'd like to add totals to the table on change of Entity, along the lines of:

Entity    Cat    Amount  
ABC       xxx     1,000  
ABC       yyy     2,000  
ABC       **Total**   3,000

I've been trying to do this inside the @foreach loop of the Model in cshtml, but can't work out how to use the combination of c# and html to achieve it.

So would be happy to learn a more appropriate approach. Also happy to understand how to mix c# and html if this is the best approach.

What I've been trying so far:

```
@{ string previousEntity = null; 
   decimal total = 0; 
 }
@foreach(var row in Model)
{
   if ((row.Entity != previousEntity) && (previousEntity != null))
   {
      <tr>
        <td>@previousEntity</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>@total</td>
      </tr>
      total = 0;
   }
   <tr>
      <td>@row.Entity</td>
     etc.
```

This results in the c# code appearing on the page in the browser  
THANKS

Comment: What kind of C# code appears as text in browser?

Comment: Thanks for the query Yamamoto san. I've tidied up my code and got it sorted. I'm still hazy about how to mix c# and html but it will probably become clearer over time!

Comment: You should not even be trying to do that in the view - Your view model should contain a property for the `Total`,and you set it in the GET method before you pass it to the view (which is a simple as `model.Total = yourCollection.Sum(x =>x.Total);`)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. What do you do if you have a list and want to add a total for each of a number of keys (e.g. entity ABC followed by entity XXX in my example above).